# Networking Socket session continuity ( Work like an IP Paging System)

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, networking

I have 2 Access Points: 1 for region A and 1 for region B .
I have a client-program and when I get connected to an access point (A) I've got an address the client then connect to the server and the server displays its address. Then the when the client connect to access point (B) its Ip Address is updated. The server needs to display the updated Address of the client.

My question is that when the address of the client changes how does the client maintain its connection and the server keep updated the address respectively?

Comment: What do you mean by "access point"? A WiFi AP?  Are the two access points on the same layer-2 network?  Do the access points run DHCP servers and assign IP addresses?  Without a lot more details it is not possible to answer this question.

Comment: Yeah 2 wifi access point , is access point is just giving the client the ip address that all . Then the client open its program in java then communicate with the server .Therefore the server Display the address that it has been given through the access point .Moreover when the client connect with the another wifi Access point it's address has been updated ,thus the client should not close it's java program and the server should always listen to the client and update that the client has changed its address

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to keep a socket connection open when the IP address changes.

Assuming your access points are routers, when the client moves from one to the other, its existing connection will become a dead connection, and the next time the client writes to its old socket, it will get an error. The client may then open a new socket connection to the server, and give the server its new address.

This is different than moving from one access point to another if they are *not* routers. In that case, the client is just connecting to the same local network a different way. It would have the *same* IP address and would not need to update the server.